Custom Cardinalities in Microsoft Access
I am designing a Basketball Season Statistics database as my final project for my Database Management class, and I am running into trouble with creating custom relationships. More specifically, I would like to edit the minimum cardinality in a relationship from one to a customer number.
For example, the conceptual relationship between my PLAYER and TEAM tables is Many:One, however, in reality, a TEAM has to have a minimum of 14 players to be considered a team. So the relationship is really Many(with minimum of 14):One.
Another example is my GAME to TEAM relationship: conceptually it is a Many:Many relationship, however it is really a Many:Min(2)Max(2) relationship (because a game has a minimum and maximum of two teams).
Is there a way to program these minimums/maximums in Access? Any help is greatly appreciated
Currently, I just have an intersection table to handle these relationships, but they are not enforcing the minimums that I need them too. I haven't tried much, because frankly I have no idea where to look.

You seem to be confused. You have ONE team with MANY players (1 to many), and you have ONE game with TWO teams (1 to many). You're trying to view the relationships in reverse.

I appreciate the comment, but I do not think I am confused. It is true that I have many players for one team, but you are only talking about one team instance. There will be many instances of teams, because many teams play in a season, and in each instance of a team, there will be many players. But regardless, this question is asking how to enforce a minimum constraint, so that a 'team' cannot be allowed to exist without a minimum of 14 players, in Microsoft Access. If you can help with that, it would be greatly appreciated.

many teams play in a season - Yes, but it's still TWO teams playing ONE game at a time. Restricting a team to a set number of players has nothing to do with one-to-many or many-to-many, and it's not something you can enforce at the database level easily - it's something that should be done at the application level. You may be able to do it in a stored procedure, but something has to cause that proc to be executed, and Access doesn't support stored procedures anyway. And it would be easy to add a flag to the TEAM record that indicates that they're eligible (have 14 players) or not.

You enforce these limits with code during data entry. It's called "data validation". This requires building forms for user interface. Did you mean "custom number" in your second sentence?

Per Ken White's comment two teams per a game is handled with structure, and since even in high school players switch teams:

per here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/multiple-foreign-keys-in-table-linked-to-same/b0ecce86-699e-4e43-956e-8306385d0dd9 the relationship tool will accept two foreign keys coming from the same primary key if the primary key's table is aliased.  In this case just drag the teams table onto the relationship surface twice.
Per June7's comment the 14 (2 in my example) members for a team constraint falls under data validation.  I usually handle my data validation during data entry as well.  In this case I would say handling what I would call a multi-level constraint is impossible at the table level anyway.
For instance I abstract the constraint to a function for clarity.  The function is public and in a code module so I can re-use it everywhere in the database.
Public Function isValidTeam(TeamID As Long, day As Date) As Boolean
    Dim minimum As Integer
    minimum = 2 '2 players to a team
    Dim teammembercount As Integer
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * FROM PlayersTeams Where TeamID = " & TeamID)
    If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
        rs.MoveFirst
        Do Until rs.EOF
            If isValidPlayer(rs!PlayerID, TeamID, day) Then
                teammembercount = teammembercount + 1
            End If
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
    If teammembercount >= minimum Then
        isValidTeam = True
    Else
        isValidTeam = False
    End If
End Function

Public Function isValidPlayer(PlayerID As Long, TeamID As Long, day As Date) As Boolean
    'debug.print isValidPlayer(1, 1, cdate("4/2/24"))
    Dim returnvalue As Boolean
    returnvalue = Nz(DLookup("PlayerTeamID", "PlayersTeamsStartDateDescending", "PlayerID = " & PlayerID & " AND TeamID = " & TeamID & " AND #" & day & "# >= StartDate AND isnull(EndDate)"), False)
    If returnvalue = False Then
        returnvalue = Nz(DLookup("PlayerTeamID", "PlayersTeamsStartDateDescending", "PlayerID = " & PlayerID & " AND TeamID = " & TeamID & " AND #" & day & "# >= StartDate AND #" & day & "#"), False)
    End If
    isValidPlayer = returnvalue
End Function

Here is an example of a form with some cascading listboxes.  If the team has enough members it is valid.



when a team is selected isValidTeam is called and the results are displayed.
Private selectedteam As Long
Public validselectedteam As Boolean
Public selectedday As Date
Public lblText As String

Public Function GetSelectedTeam() As Long
    GetSelectedTeam = selectedteam
End Function

Public Function SetSelectedTeam(value As Long)
    selectedteam = value
End Function

Private Sub lstTeams_AfterUpdate()
    SetSelectedTeam (Me.lstTeams)
    selectedday = Me.txtDate
    validselectedteam = isValidTeam(selectedteam, selectedday)
    If validselectedteam Then
        Me.txtValid.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 255)
        Me.txtValid = "valid"
    Else
        lblText = "invalid"
        Me.txtValid.ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Me.txtValid = "invalid"
    End If
    Me.chkValid = validselectedteam
    Dim sql As String
    sql = "SELECT Players.PlayerID, Players.PlayerNickName "
    sql = sql & "FROM Players INNER JOIN PlayersTeams ON Players.PlayerID = PlayersTeams.PlayerID "
    sql = sql & "WHERE (((PlayersTeams.TeamID)=[qryteamid]) AND ((PlayersTeams.StartDate)<[day]))"
    sql = Replace(Replace(sql, "[day]", "#" & Me.txtDate & "#"), "[qryteamid]", Me.lstTeams)
    Me.lstTeamPlayers.RowSource = sql
    Me.lstTeamPlayers.Visible = True
    Me.lblTeamPlayers.Visible = True
    Me.lstAvailablePlayers.Visible = True
    Me.lblAvailablePlayers.Visible = True
    Me.Refresh
End Sub


Note that If condition Then b = True Else b = False End If is the same as b = condition.
